# Stop ViewPagers inside ListView from resetting

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a `ListView` that contains rows of `ViewPager`s. When a `ViewPager` is scrolled off screen, I want to save its page position. When the user scrolls to the `ViewPager` again, I then want to restore its last saved page position.

I'm trying to accomplish this with the following code:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Row ids that will come from server-side, uniquely identifies each
    // ViewPager
    private List<String> mIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, Integer> mPagerPositions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String id = mIds.get(position);

        View rootView = convertView;
        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Integer pagerPosition = mPagerPositions.get(id);
        if (pagerPosition != null) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageChangeListener(id));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class MyPageChangeListener extends
            ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

        private String mId;

        public MyPageChangeListener(String id) {
            mId = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mPagerPositions.put(mId, position);
        }
    }
}
```

The page position gets saved on the first invocation of `setPagerPosition()`. Afterwards, when the `ViewPager` goes off-screen, `onPageSelected()` is called with the first page position that was saved — overwriting any previous `onPageSelected()` calls that occurred when the `ViewPager` was still visible.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What is the `ids` list?

Comment: The id of the row in the ListView that will come from the server side.

Comment: @Simian, try to call `setOnPageChangeListener` before calling `setCurrentItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to not overwrite the pager position when the ViewPager is not visible. There appears to be a bug in Android where onPageSelected is called when the ViewPager goes off screen when scrolling through the ListView.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (viewPager.isShown()) {
        mTopicPositions.put(mId, position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the current displayed position by `indexOfChild(viewPager.getFocusedChild())` and store it in a shared preference, and can retrieve it whenever required. Hope this helps

Comment: I need to retrieve the position when the ViewPager is visible again in the ListView. That is, when a user scrolls back to the ViewPager. Storing in SharedPreferences is overkill. And storing the View defeats the ListView's recycling of views.

Comment: No need to store the View, just store the poition. Get a global multi dimensional integer array `intPosition[ListViewPosition][ViewPagerPosition]`. Store the values in them and display the view as per value.

Comment: @Simian Did you use it? Any +ve results?